# "List of indices must be integers, not str" While getting an API image using aiohttp

Tags: python, discord.py, aiohttp, replit

I am making a discord bot that is meant to send embeds with images gotten froms APIs. I have one for a dog, and it works. The code for the dog one:

```
if message.content.lower().startswith("!dog"):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
       request = await session.get('https://some-random-api.ml/img/dog') # Make a request
       dogjson = await request.json() # Convert it to a JSON dictionary
    dogembed = discord.Embed(title="Doggy!", color=discord.Color.blue()) 
    dogembed.set_image(url=dogjson['link'])
    

await message.channel.send(embed=dogembed)
```

This works perfectly, and always. However when I try to do the same thing for a cat images, using "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search" I get this error.

[image: Error]

Here is my code for the cat one:

```
if message.content.lower().startswith("!cat"):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
       request = await session.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search') # Make a request
       catjson = await request.json() # Convert it to a JSON dictionary
    Catembed = discord.Embed(title="Kitty!", color=discord.Color.blue()) 
    Catembed.set_image(url=catjson['link'])
    
    await message.channel.send(embed=Catembed)
```

Please help me with this, I am a beginner to python and APIs.

Comment: The only difference I see in your two code, is the await in the cat one is tabbed over, try tabbing it on line with the if statement

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake in the code here, the dog one is like that too, and if i move them over it gives an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the result of your API call you'll see that it's a `list`, not a `dictionary`, as your error also suggests.

```json
[
  {
    "breeds": [],
    "id": "992",
    "url": "https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/992.jpg",
    "width": 560,
    "height": 368
  }
]
```

This means that you can't do `catjson['link']`, but you first have to take the first element of the list out of it and *then* access that field.

```py
catjson[0]['link']
```

Further, as you can see from the snippet I pasted above, `link` doesn't exist as a field in that API response. You're looking for `url`.

```py
catjson[0]['url']
```

For future reference, it never hurts to look at the output of the API (either in your browser or by `print`ing the result) before trying to use it, and also while debugging. If you get an error that a field doesn't exist, take a look at which fields *do* exist.

The reason it works fine for the dog API is because the response looks completely different, which is to be expected when using two entirely different API's.